# Image similarity of apartment photos

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-recognition

**I want to design an algorithm that would *find matches in images of the same apartment*, when put up by different real estate agents.**

Photos are relatively taken in similar time so the interior of the rooms should not change that much but of course every guys takes different pictures from different angles, etc.

(TLDR; a apartment goes for sale, and different real estate guys come in and make their own pictures, and I want to know if the given pictures from various guys are of the same place)

I know that image processing and recognition algorithm selections highly depend on the use case, so could you point me in correct direction given my use-case?

[image: image one]
[image: image two]

http://reality.bazos.sk/inzerat/56232813/Prenajom-1-izb-bytu-v-sirsom-centre.php
http://reality.bazos.sk/inzerat/56371292/-PRENAJOM-krasny-1i-byt-rekonstr-Kupeckeho-Ruzinov-BA-II.php

Comment: This question is very broad. I don't believe you will find an out-of-the-box solution for this. I would first try `homography` using `SIFT` and `RANSAC`. Later you'll probably need `object detection` to increase accuracy. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use Clarifai's Custom Training API endpoint, fairly simple and straightforward. All you would have to do is train the initial image and then compare the second to it. If the probability is high, it is likely the same apartment. For example:

In javascript, to declare a positive it is:

```
clarifai.positive('http://example.com/apartment1.jpg', 'firstapartment', callback);
```

And a negative is:

```
clarifai.negative('http://example.com/notapartment1.jpg', 'firstapartment', callback);
```

You don't necessarily have to do a negative, but it could only help. Then, when you are comparing images to the first aparment, you do:

```
clarifai.predict('http://example.com/someotherapartment.jpg', 'firstapartment', callback);
```

This will give you a probability regarding the likeness of the photo to what you've trained ('firstapartment'). This API is basically doing machine learning without the hassle of the actual machine. Clarifai's API also has a tagging input that is extremely accurate with some basic tags. The API is free for a certain number of calls/month. Definitely worth it to check out for this case.

Answer (score 1):

As user Shaked mentioned in a comment, this is a difficult problem. Even if you knew the position and orientation of each camera in space, and also the characteristics of each camera, it wouldn't be a trivial problem to match the images.

A "bag of words" (BoW) approach may be of use here. Rather than try to identify specific objects and/or deduce the original 3D scene, you determine what "feature descriptors" can distinguish objects from one another in your image sets.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision

Imagine you could describe the two images by the relative locations of textures and colors:

- horizontal-ish line segments at far left
- red blob near center left
- green clumpy thing at bottom left
- bright round object near top left
- ...

then for a reasonably constrained set of images (e.g. photos just within a certain zip code), you may be able to yield a good match between the two images above.

The Wikipedia article on BoW may look a bit daunting, but I think if you hunt around you'll find an article that describes "bag of words" for image processing clearly. I've seen a very good demo of a BoW approach used to identify objects such as boats and delivery vans in arbitrary video streams, and it worked impressively well. I wish I had a copy of the presentation to pass along.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't suspect the image to change much, you could try the standard first step of any standard structure-from-motion algorithm to establish a notion of similarity between a pair of images. Any pair of images are similar if they contain a number of matching image features larger than a threshold which satisfy the geometrical constraint of the scene as well. For a general scene, that geometrical constraint is given by a Fundamental Matrix F computed using a subset of matching features.

Here are the steps. I have inserted the opencv method for each step, but you could write your methods too:

1. Read the pair of images. Use `img = cv2.imread(filename)`.
2. Use SIFT/SURF to detect image features/descriptors in both images.
   `sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
   kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(img,None)`
3. Match features using the descriptors. 
   `bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True) 
   matches = bf.match(des1,des2)`
4. Use RANSAC to compute funamental matrix.
   `cv2.findFundamentalMatrix(pts1, pts2, cv2.FM_RANSAC, 3, 0.99, mask)`
5. `mask` contains all the inliers. Simply count them to determine if the number of matches satisfying geometrical constraint is large enough.
6. CAUTION: In case of a planar scene, we use homography instead of a fundamental matrix and the steps described above work out pretty nicely because homography takes a point to a corresponding point in the other image. However, Fundamental matrix takes a point to the corresponding epipolar line in the other image, which makes the entire process a bit less stable. So I would recommend trying these steps a few more times with a little bit of jitter to the feature locations and collating the evidence over more than one trial to make the decision. You can also use more advanced steps to introduce robustness to this process but only if the steps described above don't yield the results you need.